# What is the correct CSV format for tuples when loading data with DSBulk?

Tags: cassandra, tuples, cqlsh, dsbulk

I recently started using Cassandra for my new project and doing some load testing.

I have a scenario where I’m doing dsbulk load using CSV like this,

```
$ dsbulk load -url <csv path> -k <keyspace> -t <table> -h <host> -u <user> -p <password> -header true -cl LOCAL_QUORUM
```

My CSV file entries looks like this,

```
userid birth_year created_at                  freq
1234   1990       2023-01-13T23:27:15.563Z    {1234:{"(1, 2)": 1}}
```

Column types,

```
userid bigint PRIMARY KEY,
birth_year int,
created_at timestamp,
freq map<bigint, frozen<map<frozen<tuple<tinyint, smallint>>, smallint>>>
```

The issue is, for column `freq`, I try different ways of setting the value in csv like below, but not able to insert the row using `dsbulk`

1. Let’s say if I set freq as `{1234:{[1, 2]: 1}}`,
   com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.workflow.commons.schema.InvalidMappingException: Could not map field freq to variable freq; conversion from Java type java.lang.String to CQL type Map(BIGINT => Map(Tuple(TINYINT, SMALLINT) => SMALLINT, not frozen), not frozen) failed for raw value: {1234:{[1,2]: 1}}
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse ‘{1234:{[1, 2]: 1}}’ as Json
   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (‘[’ (code 91)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
   at [Source: (String)“{1234:{[1, 2]: 1}}“; line: 1, column: 9]
2. If I set freq as `{\"1234\":{\"[1, 2]\":1}}`,
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting record to contain 4 fields but found 5.
3. If I set freq as `{1234:{"[1, 2]": 1}} or {1234:{"(1, 2)": 1}}`,
   Source: 1234,80,2023-01-13T23:27:15.563Z,“{1234:{“”[1, 2]“”: 1}}” java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting record to contain 4 fields but found 5.

But in `COPY FROM TABLE` command, the value for freq `{1234:{[1, 2]:1}}` inserts into DB without any error, the value in DB looks like this `{1234: {(1, 2): 1}}`

I guess the JSON not accepting array(tuple) as key when I try with dsbulk? Can someone advise me what’s the issue and how to fix this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading data using the [DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html), the CSV format for CQL `tuple` type is different from the format used by the `COPY ... FROM` command because DSBulk uses a different parser.

Formatting the CSV data is particularly challenging in your case because the column contains multiple nested CQL collections.

#### `InvalidMappingException`

The JSON parser used by DSBulk doesn't accept parentheses `()` when enclosing tuples. It also expects tuples to be enclosed in double quotes `"` otherwise you'll get errors like:

```
com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.workflow.commons.schema.InvalidMappingException: \
  Could not map field ... to variable ...; \
  conversion from Java type ... to CQL type ... failed for raw value: ...
   ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse '...' as Json
   ...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: \
  Unexpected character ('(' (code 91)): was expecting either valid name character \
  (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
   ...
```

#### `IllegalArgumentException`

Since values for tuples contain a comma (`,`) as a separator, DSBulk incorrectly parses the rows and it thinks each row contains more fields than expected and throws an `IllegalArgumentException`, for example:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting record to contain 2 fields but found 3.
```

#### Solution

Just to make it easier, here is the schema for the table I'm using as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE inttuples (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    inttuple map<frozen<tuple<tinyint, smallint>>, smallint>
)
```

In this example CSV file, I've used the pipe character (`|`) as a delimiter:

```
id|inttuple
1|{"[2,3]":4}
```

Here's another example that uses tabs as the delimiter:

```
id      inttuple
1       {"[2,3]":4}
```

Note that you will need to specify the delimiter with either `-delim '|'` or `-delim '\t'` when running DSBulk. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, Erick, for looking into this and giving a clear explanation. Let me try this approach and update this forum(if needed).